# splice not working while using in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am trying to remove an item from array but its not working i am using following code

```
vm.Continue = function () {
    $scope.invalidList = [];
    if (vm.errorexsist === true) {
        var table = document.getElementById('errortabel');
        for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
            if (r > 0) {
                $scope.invalidList.push({
                    Error: table.rows[r].cells[0].val   ,
                    FirstName: table.rows[r].cells[1].children[0].value,
                    Email: table.rows[r].cells[2].children[0].value,
                    PhoneNumber: table.rows[r].cells[3].children[0].value,
                    Location: table.rows[r].cells[4].children[0].value,
                    Department: table.rows[r].cells[5].children[0].value
                });
            }
        }
        var i = $scope.invalidList.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (IsEmailValid($scope.invalidList[i].Email) === true && IsPhoneNumValid($scope.invalidList[i].PhoneNumber) === true) {
                $scope.invalidList.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }  
    }
};
```

the above code always removes item at zero while condition of if else does not meet.

Comment: `i <= $scope.invalidList.length`? Also, when removing several items from an array it should be done from last index to first, so when you remove an item the rest to check remain in the same place.

Comment: Is email AND phone number? How can something be both an email and a phone number?

Comment: do you need to usee splice? Why don't you try usnig Array.prototype.reduce? It would be just a tiny bit more verbose, but easier to understand and modify

Comment: splice modifies the array, updates the length and you're using the length in for loop and therefore the issue. Use while loop instead, use local variable to store length before the loop

Comment: How about something like `$scope.invalidList = $scope.invalidList.filter(({Email, PhoneNumber}) => !(IsEmailValid(Email) && IsPhoneNumValid(PhoneNumber)))`?

Comment: @dcg i've updated my code, and tried reverse iteration but still facing same issue

Comment: @georgeawg you are right, but it is not checking same item for email and phone both are different items

Comment: @ScottSauyet i have also tried this but having same issue. ps: i have also updated my code, can you please have a look

Comment: The answer from Jordan Burnett should work, as should my comment above.  If these don't, please try to reduce this to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one which we can try in a snippet.  There's a good chance that in doing so, you will find the answer yourself; but if not, it will give us much more to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.splice` will modify the length of an array, so you should iterate backwards through your array otherwise every time you call splice, the index and length of your for loop become obsolete.

```
var i = $scope.invalidList.length
while (i--) {
    if (IsEmailValid($scope.invalidList[i].Email) === true && IsPhoneNumValid($scope.invalidList[i].PhoneNumber) === true) {   
        $scope.invalidList.splice(i, 1);   
    }
}
```

If you're looking to remove items from an array based on a condition, `Array.filter` is designed for this exact purpose:

```
$scope.invalidList = $scope.invalidList.filter(item => !IsEmailValid(item.Email) || !IsPhoneNumValid(item.PhoneNumber))
```

Comment: (thank you for your answer)
i have updated my code. this function is called at button click and there is a html table which holds the invalid items, after clicking the button code should remove the item which is edited as valid in table and then remove that i tem from list so that it will force user to completely correct the data, (but it is not behaving like it should be)